# HTML canvas drawImage when window minimized

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webrtc

I am building an Electron webRTC app in which I need to send a MediaStream from one window to another. The sender window contains a video element, which is copied onto a canvas element, converted to a MediaStream using captureStream() function, and sent to the receiver window using P2P connection.

When both windows(sender, receiver) are running on screen, the media transmission works fine. However, I want the sender window to be able to send the media even when it is minimized to the taskbar. Currently, the video on the receiver side freezes once the sender window get minimized. I suspect the canvas element stop capturing the original video once the window gets minimized.

This is how I create a canvas copy of a video element:

```
/**
 * Create a copy of HTMLvideo in HTMLcanvas for
 * Get reference of the video, width and height as parameters
 * Return canvas object
 */
function copyVideo(video, width, height, frameRate) {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(function() {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }, frameRate);
    return canvas;
}
```

My question is, what exactly happens to my canvas when a browser window get minimized? Is there a way to continue running drawImage while the window is minimized?

Comment: Your interval stops ticking when the window is minimized. I provide a link to a more complex question as a possible dupe target, where a similar problem is addressed. You just have to take what you want from there. Also, if all you do is sending a video stream, why do you go through the canvas API ? Can't you just do `videoElement.captureStream()` and send the resulting MediaStream instead ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing JavaScript for multiple browser display at high fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634509/optimizing-javascript-for-multiple-browser-display-at-high-fps)

Comment: Oh and actually, if you are using `canvas.captureStream`, depending on which version of chromium your Electron is using, maybe your are still facing this [now fixed bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=653548#c1)

Comment: Hi Kaiido, thanks for your comment! I will look into your link. The reason I could not use videoElement.captureStream() directly was because my video does not have a src attribute, instead it only has srcObject. Hence, I was kept getting " Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLMediaElement': The media element must have a source" error. Using a canvas to make a video copy was my work around it.

Comment: And where does this srcObject comes from ? IIRC, browsers still only allow MediaStream as srcObject *(while specs say that MediaSource and Blobs should work too...)*, so why not send this MediaStream directly ?

Comment: I am actually working on top of existing codebase, and the srcObject for the video element switches by certain events. If I use that MediaStream, I need to listen to the mediaSwitched event and resend the stream to the target window. But my supervisor does not want me to access the lower level of the application, so I am trying to capture the video instead so that I do not have to react to the mediaSwitched event.

Comment: ... Seems overly complicated, with a lot of quirks, like the one I mentioned in [c#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156701/#comment-77284903) and others alike which may not have been found or created yet. These are upcoming technologies, not yet stabilized. Also, it will force you to use [some rough workarounds like the one I pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634509/optimizing-javascript-for-multiple-browser-display-at-high-fps) even when stabilized. So all in all, in your position, I would talk to your manager again.

Comment: Ps: you can access the MediaStream currently set to your video element by just requesting `videoElement.srcObject`. You can also listen to the `videoElement.ondurationchange` or other of its events to know when the source has changed. This way you can easily switch to the new stream, without accessing low-level of whatever. And since I think we're digging up some XY issue, if it is really the case, it may be a good idea to post again this question, with your exact scenario.

Comment: Dear my friend Kaiido, you were right this is a XY problem, and your `videoElement.ondurationchange` completely solved my problem. There is no need to stick to the canvas anymore. Thank you so much :)